# LARAVEL, data increment

Tags: laravel

I would like to make an auto increment with a date + a number. Example: 16022017-1. However I can not add the date + the dash + the number.

1- I retrieve the latest invoices in the database

```
$exist = Contrats::where('number','like','%'.$dateNow->format('dmY').'%')->orderBy('number', 'desc')->get();
```

2- Here my condition adds value after the date however I can not add the "-" and the number.

```
if (count($exist) == 0){
        $date = new \DateTime(null);
        $contrat->number = $date->format('dmY');
    } elseif (count($exist) == 1){
        $date = new \DateTime(null);
        $contrat->number = $date->format('dmY'), '-', 1;
    } else {
        echo "pb";
    }
```

Do you have an idea how I can increment my date, dash and number? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick shoot from the hip answer as i am munching on my salad... Seems that your suffix (number after the date) is the actual count since you seem to be skipping the first instance (0). Eloquent returns a collection... use the ->count() ...

```
if ($exist->count() > 0){
    $date = new \DateTime(null);
    $contrat->number = $date->format('dmY') . '-' . $exists->count();
} else {
    $date = new \DateTime(null);
    $contrat->number = $date->format('dmY');
}
```